# Robotium and Service Test

Tags: android, android-service, robotium, android-testing

I have an Application which binds to a Service using #startService. The Service is a remote service, defined using AIDL.

I want to write a Robotium 4.x Test which binds to a "Mock" Service which delivers some Test data so that I can control which data gets delivered by the Service. I do not understand enough to setup such a scenario.

My first attempt was to invoke some Method on the Activity wich gets launched by my ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and simple pass in a ServiceConnection and manually call #onServiceConnected to simulate the callback from the System.

```
 activity.setConnection(new FakeServiceConnection());
```

This always results in an

```
 Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'
```

as it seem the ServiceConnection will be already seen by the Android Runtime in some way.

I read about RenamingDelegateContext and IsolatedContext, but i dont know how to control or set the creation on the Service when the runtime #startService gets called.

Documentation says that I may have to override corresponding Methods like this.

```
public class ServiceRenamingContext extends RenamingDelegatingContext {

    @Override
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("I got called!!!!");
        // return super.startService(service);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("I got called!!!!");
        // return super.stopService(name);
    }

    public ServiceRenamingContext(Context context, String filePrefix) {
        super(context, filePrefix);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("I got called!!!!");

        // return super.bindService(service, conn, flags);
    }
}
```

As you see this just throws some kind of exception to see that it gets called by the runtime. But nothing happens.

Any hint how to setup this is much appreciated.

I think I didn't understand how to setup a special context like mine using the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

cheers